# Not loading the right image when preloading, works in firefox but not properly in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, preload, image-preloader

Preloading:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02.png" imagesrcset="http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-300x169.png 300w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-1024x576.png 1024w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-370x208.png 370w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-330x186.png 330w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-374x210.png 374w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-480x270.png 480w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-561x316.png 561w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-660x371.png 660w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-690x388.png 690w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-768x432.png 768w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-978x550.png 978w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-990x557.png 990w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-1089x613.png 1089w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-1152x648.png 1152w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-150x84.png 150w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02.png 1200w" imagesizes="(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px">
```

Image:

```
<img width="1200" height="675" src="http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02.png 1200w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-300x169.png 300w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-1024x576.png 1024w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-370x208.png 370w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-330x186.png 330w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-374x210.png 374w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-480x270.png 480w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-561x316.png 561w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-660x371.png 660w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-690x388.png 690w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-768x432.png 768w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-978x550.png 978w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-990x557.png 990w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-1089x613.png 1089w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-1152x648.png 1152w, http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test-02-150x84.png 150w" sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px">
```

As you can see in the [image], it has only loaded the `test-02.png` and not the image relative to the browser size. Note that I have created a custom device in chrome and set the `Device pixel ratio` to `2`.

But here in firefox as you can see in the [image] it has loaded the `test-02-768x432.png`. I have also set `DPR: 2`.

To test it more, I changed the preload path to another image path.

[image: preload with some other path]

I got that it would load the image properly in the right size and also the image preloading is working(with the new path I have set). But when I change it back to its previous value, the image to be shown is `test-02.png` while it must be `test-02-768x432.png`. So it seems the preloading with the same path in `img` tag is making problem.

How can I fix it? Is it a bug in Google Chrome?

Chrome Version: 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**UPDATE**

I sorted the paths by width ascendingly. It seems the chrome will load only the last image in the `srcset` attribute and the problem is not related to preloading.

**Update**

I got that it might be a bug/feature in chrome. Here is a reference:

https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/issues/133

Comment: are you using some bundler tools like webpack? do you use code splitting?

Comment: No nothing. The code I have sent is just a simple html.